# django modelAdmin save_model() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)

Tags: python, django

I am using double stars still it keeps on saying `save_model() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)` or `save_model() takes exactly 3 arguments (6 given)` for this code:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, *kwwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user==obj.author:
            super(ArticleAdmin,self).save_model(self, request, obj, *kwwargs)
        else:
            raise ValidationError("author must be you")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What django version?

Comment: django-admin --version 1.7.6

Comment: Sorry, it's not about the django version. I just spot the mistake in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass the `self` argument when calling the super class method. So, it will be:

```
super(ArticleAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

> You have a typo, it's suppose to be `kwargs` not `kkwargs`
>
> And in `kwargs`, you normally use double asterisk `**kwargs` instead of single asterisk. This include those in your function definition. `def save_model(self, request, obj, **kwargs):` Single asterisk is for `*args`. *kwargs stands for keyword arguments*.
>
> In python 3, u just need to use `super().save_model(request, obj, **kwargs)`